# List filtering by date range ( sharepoint foundation 2010 )

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter, foundation

How can I filter a list by date range in `SharePoint 2010 Foundation`?

I found out how in `SharePoint2010`, but in the Foundation version I haven't the Filter Web Parts and can't find where to download them (if it is possible).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but I believe this will help. In the SharePoint Ribbon, click "Modify View". Once the page has loaded, scroll down and find the section "Filter". Select the option to "Show items only when the following is true".

Choose the appropriate column in the first dropdown. In this situation choose "Created" or "Modified". In the second dropdown, choose the appropriate condition which you want to filter the date by. Choose "is greater than". In the blank type the date you want the range to begin with. For example, "10/02/2013".

If you want to pick an end date for the range, select "And" and then do the same process as above, except you want the second dropdown to say "is less than".

Comment: yeah, that is the only solution Foundation version lets, but it's not that "user-friendly" like inserting a couple of coded web parts ( possible only in normal mode);<br/>
we resolved that with a third part component ( ... )

i mark this as answer, thank you